# Python Add CC Recipients in Reply through Outlook

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

I am searching an item in outlook through subject , want to do replay to all adding 3 ids in CC.

Easily able to add more recipients in To but not in CC please help

```
import win32com.client

outlook=win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox= outlook.Folders.Item(1).Folders['Inbox']
messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetLast()
count=0
for i, message in enumerate(messages):
    # Search Mail
    # if message.subject=='Search Filter by Subject':
    rplyall=message.ReplyAll()
    rplyall.Recipients.Add('hitesh.kumar@bhartiaxa.com') # Sender of the mail
    rplyall.Recipients.CC('one.more@abc.com')     # Trying to do this
    rplyall.Copy('one.more@abc.com')
    rplyall.Body='Testing reply all'
    rplyall.Subject = 'Subject Reply to all 2'

    rplyall.Send()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add CC recipients by editing the `CC` property directly or updating the `Type` property of the returned from the returned Recipient object from `Recipients.Add`

Updating the recipient type

```
newCC = rplyall.Recipients.Add('one.more@abc.com')     
newCC.Type = 2 #2 = olCC
```

Changing the CC property

```
rplyall.CC = 'one.more@abc.com;two.more@abc.com'
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipients

Comment: CC property is very much editable, you can either call Recipients.Add or set the CC property to a semicoln separated list: `rplyall.CC = 'user1@test.demo;user2@test2.demo;user3@test3.demo'`

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Absolutely correct - updated to reflect.

Answer (score 0):

Correcting the answer to my own question post getting the answer from Mike in above post.

```
 import win32com.client

outlook=win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox= outlook.Folders.Item(1).Folders['Inbox']
messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetFirst()
count=0

for i, message in enumerate(messages):
    print(message.subject)
    rplyall = message.ReplyAll()
    rplyall.Recipients.Add('hitesh@abc.com') # Sender of the mail
    rplyall.CC = 'deepak@abc.com'
    rplyall.Body = 'Testing reply all'
    rplyall.Subject = 'Subject Reply to all TEST'
    rplyall.Send()
```

Comment: Absolutely not.

Comment: @ Dmitry Streblechenko , I did search long time would appropriate if you can share the solution as well.

Comment: Did you not see the answer by Mike above?